# GET/UPDATE custom field in products which is from custom post type by using REST API in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce, endpoint, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using a custom plugin in WooCommerce. In that custom plugin, one custom post type inventory is created. I am mapping that custom post type to a product meta field. But updating through REST API meta fields to map post type is not updating. Custom product types are also not updated through the REST API. How to update those fields through the REST API.

Custom post type mapping to Product screen:

[image: mapping inventory to product]
Custom Post type creation Screen:
[image: inventory post creation]

Below is the response I got when I updated the product type through the API:

```
  {
      "code": "rest_invalid_param",
      "message": "Invalid parameter(s): type",
      "data": {
      "status": 400,
      "params": {
                   "type": "type is not one of simple, grouped, external, and variable."
                 },
      "details": {
             "type": {
             "code": "rest_not_in_enum",
             "message": "type is not one of simple, grouped, external, and variable.",
             "data": null
            }
           }
         }
        }
```

If anyone has faced this issue, please let me know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the plugin you are using have API support, I would suggest you ask them about it. As default WC API only supports simple, grouped, external and variable product types.

If you remove the field "type" from your request when updating it should work.